# How can I hide TeamViewer icon in taskbar?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar, notification-area, teamviewer

I am unable hide the TeamViewer's icon in the notification area.

I've tried "hide always" using the taskbar properties, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to make it actually disappear?

Comment: What is better than a random downvote without a comment?